# Mapping IQueryable class from Automapper

Tags: automapper

Does Automapper works with IQueryable?

I have 2 Query

```cs
IQueryable<V_ImageUpload> Query1;
IQueryable<V_ImageUpload> Query2;

Mapper.CreateMap<IQueryable<V_ImageUpload_WithReceiptBackup>, IQueryable<V_ImageUpload>>();
Query1 = Mapper.Map<IQueryable<V_ImageUpload_WithReceiptBackup>, IQueryable<V_ImageUpload>>(Query2);
```

Exception occured is:

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not used AutoMapper (so this was an excuse to try it out!), but there are [queryable extensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) available.  Both your queryables are of the same type, so I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve, but perhaps something like this is what you want, which takes an `IQueryable<V_ImageUpload_WithReceiptBackup>` and converts it to an `IQueryable<V_ImageUpload>`:

```cs
IQueryable<V_ImageUpload_WithReceiptBackup> query1;
IQueryable<V_ImageUpload> query2;
// Only map the actual type, not the queryable types
Mapper.CreateMap<V_ImageUpload_WithReceiptBackup, V_ImageUpload>();
query2 = query1.Project().To<V_ImageUpload>();
```

The `.Project().To<V_ImageUpload>()` keeps it as `IQueryable`, while `Mapper.Map` would end up with a `List/IEnumerable`.  I only tested this out with LINQ to Objects, but hopefully it works with Entity Framework, or whatever you are using.